# Attempt to index a nil value in a script

Tags: lua

I'm trying to write a lua script to assist in modifying a game, and it keeps breaking on one particular line of one of my assistant libraries.

odfWriter.lua:

```
require 'loopsetup'
require 'ioWriter'
local open = {}
odfWriter = class{
    writer = false
}
odfWriter[open] = false

function odfWriter:open(name)
    if not self[open] then
        self.writer = ioWriter()
        self.writer:open(name)
        self[open] = true
    else
        error("tried to open an already open writer")
    end
end

function odfWriter:write(args)
    self.writer:write(args.Key .. " = ") --<-- error is here, when trying to access args
    if args.Type == "seqstrings" then
        for k,v in pairs(args.Value) do
            self.writer:write("\"" .. v .. "\" ")
        end
    elseif args.Type == "string" then
        self.writer:write("\"" .. args.Value .. "\"")
    elseif args.Type == "seqnumbers" then
        for k,v in pairs(args.Value) do
            self.writer:write(tostring(v) .. " ")
        end
    elseif args.Type == "number" then
        self.writer:write(tostring(args.Value))
    elseif args.Type == "boolean" then
        if args.Value == true then
            self.writer:write("1")
        elseif args.Value == false then
            self.writer:write("0")
        end
    end
    self.writer:write("\n")
end
function odfWriter:close()
    if self[open] then
        self.writer:close()
        self.writer = false
        self[open] = false
    else
        error("tried to close an already closed writer")
    end
end
```

loopSetup.lua

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--  file        : loopsetup.lua
--  description : provides global access to all of the (known) members
--                of the loop.simple code (for easier access)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
require 'loop.simple'
class = loop.simple.class
classof = loop.simple.classof
initclass = loop.simple.initclass
instanceof = loop.simple.instanceof
isclass = loop.simple.isclass
memberof = loop.simple.memberof
members = loop.simple.members
new = loop.simple.new
rawnew = loop.simple.rawnew
subclassof = loop.simple.subclassof
superclass = loop.simple.superclass
```

ioWriter.lua:

```
local loaded = require('loopsetup')
assert(loaded, 'loopsetup not loaded')
local open = {}
ioWriter = class{
    stream = false
}
ioWriter[open] = false
function ioWriter:open(name)
    if not self[open] then
        self.stream = io.open(name, "w")
        self[open] = true
    else
        error("attempted to open an already open writer")
    end
end
function ioWriter:write(str)
    self.stream:write(str)
end
function ioWriter:writeLine(str)
    self.stream:write(str .. '\n')
end
function ioWriter:close(self)
    if self[open] then
        self.stream:flush()
        self.stream:close()
        self.stream = false
        self[open] = false
    else
        error("attempted to close an already closed writer")
    end
end
```

test code:

```
require 'loopsetup'
require 'odfWriter'
local odf = odfWriter()
odf:open('test.odf')
local line1Data = {
    Type = "seqstrings",
    Key = "engineTargetHardpoints",
    Value = {"hp01", "hp02", "hp03"}
}
odf:write(line1data)
odf:close()
```

Why do i have this error when i am clearly passing in a valid table to odfwriter.write?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what game are you modifying?

Comment: An old one, actually a modification to one. Star Trek Armada 2 Fleet Operations. It's at www.fletops.net

Comment: +1 for a well presented question.

Comment: I'll have to remember that minimal description + lots of code + glue = great presentation! :D

Comment: @RCIX, it sure beats the too usual pattern of questions that are just "it didn't work. why?"  Test code is always good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in your test code, you have a typo:

```
line1data ~= line1Data
```

You also have a typo in ioWriter.lua in the close method:

```
function ioWriter:close(self)
```

should be

```
function ioWriter:close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explicitly checked that everything implementing `odf:open()` succeeded. My concern is that it looks like the whole flow control in of `odf:open()` seems to assume that everything succeeded. Is it possible that it didn't, and as a result that at the line indicated the error is caused by attempting to index `self.writer` containing `nil`?

It could be `nil` as opposed to `false` if `odfWriter:open()` didn't successfully execute the constructor `self.writer = ioWriter()` for example. I'm not a regular user of loop, so I might be barking up the wrong tree, but...

If that were happening, it would be easy to get a message that is confused about which index was at fault.

Perhaps dropping calls to `assert()` in a few choice spots would be productive.